# .htaccess RewriteRule appends old Wordpress directory path

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Debian/Apache VPS with Wordpress.
I was trying to use this code to redirect all 'www' URLs to non-www addresses:

```
# Redirect if www.site.net (case-insensitive) to site.net
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.site\.net [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://site.net/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

But this would unexpectedly redirect **www.site.net** to **site.net/site.net** and
**www.site.net/example** to **site.net/site.net/example** — I deactivated all WP plugins to check again but with no effect.

Previously my WP installation path was /var/www/site.net/ but I moved it to /var/www/ 
My /etc/apache2/sites-available/site.net looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName site.net
 ServerAlias www.site.net
 DocumentRoot /var/www
 DirectoryIndex index.php
 <Directory /var/www/>
   Options FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
 </Directory>
 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Please, advise, what do I need to do to make it work properly?

Comment: My Wordpress and Site URLs in WP Settings both point to http://site.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is to create a new virtualhost in your config file which is there to do the redirection. It's much more efficient than using mod_rewrite and easier to read what's going on too.

```
# to do the redirection
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.site.net
  RedirectMatch permanent (.*) http://site.net$1
</VirtualHost>

# actual website
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName site.net
  DocumentRoot /var/www/
  # .. etc .. 
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me. But still I'm afraid I'll have more troubles with htaccess (e.g. I'm trying to set up feed url to feedburner redirection and it doesn't redirect anywhere (same url). Do you have any ideas why the problem occurred at all?

Comment: Good question - I've just tested your code out on my box and it's working as you intended. What version of apache are you using? I'm on 2.2.22